# How can i sum the elements of the list in the nested dictionary

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, nested, list-comprehension

I have an dictionary as below

```
dict= {
('201', '1'): {'357': [1, 67500], '360': [1, 40000], '362': [2, 45000], '365': [1, 12500]},
('301', '2'): {'322': [5, 237500]},
('301', '1'): {'325': [10, 675000]}
}
```

I want to get the result as below :

```
'''165000 is the sum of the second elements of the lists e.g. [1, 67500]'''

{
('201', '1'): 165000},
('301', '2'): 237500},
('301', '1'): 675000}
}
```

Can you show your codes---
any solutions would be helpful - comprehension, Counter and so on

```
{('201', '1'): 165000},('301', '2'): 237500},('301', '1'): 675000}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
dct = {
    ("201", "1"): {
        "357": [1, 67500],
        "360": [1, 40000],
        "362": [2, 45000],
        "365": [1, 12500],
    },
    ("301", "2"): {"322": [5, 237500]},
    ("301", "1"): {"325": [10, 675000]},
}

out = {}
for k, v in dct.items():
    out[k] = sum(vv for _, vv in v.values())

print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
{("201", "1"): 165000, ("301", "2"): 237500, ("301", "1"): 675000}
```

---

Or:

```py
out = {k: sum(vv for _, vv in v.values()) for k, v in dct.items()}
```